# How to "insert" a date in the table which is 750 days before current date?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I want to insert date in a table which is 750 days before the current date.

Comment: `... SET column = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 750 DAY`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two simple functions:

CURDATE()

DATE_ADD()

Reference: [MySQL Date and Time functions](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/date-and-time-functions.php#:%7E:text=In%20MySQL%20the%20CURDATE(),is%20used%20in%20the%20function.&text=In%20MySQL%20the%20CURRENT_DATE%20returns,is%20used%20in%20the%20function.) [MySQL DATE_ADD() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp)

```
create table dtTable (col datetime);
insert into dtTable values
(curdate()),
(date_add(curdate(), interval -750 day));
```

[DB fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a9c45/1)